# How to persist just certain fields of entity in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

At first I want to implement security policy that allow to user persist just certain fields depending on roles, secondly when user press button 'Save', it should save just fields that has been touched.

For it I want have ability dynamically (in runtime) say to hibernate which fields I want persist (like Projection in Criteria). Does somebody knows how to do this?

ps I want persist mapped entity